# Will the peer pressure badge eventually get recommended as next badge?

Tags: discussion, badges

My "Select your next badge" recommends going for the Epic badge, and there are still a few alternatives to work on as well:

[image]

Assuming that I had obtained all the badges I can select from, apart from "Peer Pressure", would that badge actually be recommended as the next goal?

Comment: I presume don't see why not. [I'll let you know for sure in another 44 questions.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6JKO1.png) (If I don't get Peer Pressure before then, that is.) Or someone might answer conclusively [on the main meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272694/what-does-select-your-next-badge-popup-look-like-when-you-have-got-all-badges).

Comment: Thanks for the links, I always forget to look at the main meta when I happen to have a question. Let us know if you need help getting Peer Pressure ;-)

Comment: Suggesting it could make sense if there is already a suitable post to delete. The *Go get it* link points to a search for posts to delete. In my case that search generate no results. I checked because I was wondering whether the *Go get it* link might have linked to a place to create a suitable post to delete, but of course that would have been sending the wrong signals.